# Does surjectivity of the representation imply irreducibility?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Basically what the title asks. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra and let $\rho : \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow End(V)$ be a representation. Suppose $\rho$ is surjective. Does it follow that $\rho$ is irreducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, surjectivity does not imply irreducibility. One remark is, that every (finite-dimensional) irreducible representation of a complex solvable Lie algebra is $1$-dimensional because of Lie's Theorem.

Comment: Why not? Let $v \neq 0$ in $V$, then $\rho(\mathfrak{g})v=End(V)(v)=V$. Is that incorrect?